# ImageView coordinate (0,0) has space

Tags: android, imageview, coordinates

Im facing the next problem: I have an imageView that change the size programmatically because de density hdpi has a 480x800 resolution. I change the size with layoutParams. 
After I change the size, I want to position the imageView. When I position the view for example to the coordinate (0,0) I saw that between the imageView and the limit of the screen is a little space, like 25 inches. The imageView moves to other place and when I want to position it again to (0,0), the space between the imageView and the limit of the screen disappear. Why is happening that? I need to fix that because the first time is showing wrong, I don’t want the space!
Hope your understand

Greets

Comment: Don't really understand what you want to achieve. Also post code please

Comment: My first question is,when i position a ImageView to (0,0) is not is not exctly in the left top corner. Between the imageView and the limit screen is a little space.