# Android bringToFront() View API <= 16

Tags: android, view, z-order, bringtofront

When I was testing my app, I realized that if I use a device with API <= 16 the method `bringToFront()` does not work! How can I do this for APIs less than 16? When I touch a view, I need to bring it to the front!
With API 17 or greater, `bringToFront()` works.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just by using the documentation you can read there (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) that:

> Change the view's z order in the tree, so it's on top of other sibling
>   views. This ordering change may affect layout, if the parent container
>   uses an order-dependent layout scheme (e.g., LinearLayout). Prior to
>   KITKAT this method should be followed by calls to requestLayout() and
>   invalidate() on the view's parent to force the parent to redraw with
>   the new child ordering.

So it does work on early APIs, it's just that you should use it a little bit differently ;)

Comment: My views are inside a RelativeLayout, i have to do relativeLayout.invalidate() or requestLayout()? or view.invalidate()?

Comment: Thanks, i ask if API <= 16 do relativeLayout.invalidate() and work!

Comment: i have another question, maybe you can answer it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33134905/imageview-coordinate-0-0-has-space

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#bringToFront()):

> public void bringToFront ()
>   Added in API level 1
>
> Change the view's z order in the tree, so it's on top of other sibling
>   views. This ordering change may affect layout, if the parent container
>   uses an order-dependent layout scheme (e.g., LinearLayout). **Prior to
>   KITKAT this method should be followed by calls to requestLayout() and
>   invalidate() on the view's parent to force the parent to redraw with
>   the new child ordering**.